# How to add a list<T> to view with a single model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, grid.mvc

Getting an error while trying to add a grid to my detail page.  The error is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'GridMvc.Html.HtmlGrid`1[MyApp.Models.RecipientActivityMetadata]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.Models.RecipientActivityMetadata]'.

MVC4 View is a combination of a detail page and a list.  I am using a viewmodel that looks like this:

```
public class FormViewModel()
{
    public RecipientMetadata Recipient { get; set; }
    public StudentActivityMetadata StudentActivity    { get; set; }
    public List<RecipientActivityMetadata> RecipientActivites { get; set; }
}
```

The view top is:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ViewModels.FormViewModel
```

and it renders a partial view which contains the list:

```
@Html.Partial("_grid", Model.RecipientActivites)
```

and the partial looks like this:

```
@using GridMvc.Html
@model List<MyApp.Models.RecipientActivityMetadata>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div>
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(c => c.ActCount).Titled("Activity Num");
        columns.Add(c => c.ActivityType).Titled("Activity Type");
        columns.Add(c => c.FundCode).Titled("FundCode");
        columns.Add(c => c.Hours).Titled("Hours");
    }).WithPaging(10)
</div>
```

Comment: @Html.Grid has a partial called _grid to render. So, looks like you need to rename this partial to something different or specify full path of the partial view. I have not used MVC.Grid but from documentation, it looked like that.

Comment: That was it, I changed the name and now it works.  I didn't even notice that in the docs.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Go ahead and post the answer so i can mark it.

Comment: You are welcome. I have post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### From Comment to Answer

According to the documentation provided by [Grid.Mvc](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start&referringTitle=Home), `@Html.Grid` uses a partial view `_Grid.cshtml`. Because your partial view also has same name, the solution is to use a different name for your partial view.